# Android Activity Interface setting

Tags: android, android-studio

What's the name of this area in android?
How can I adjust its height?
I want to make it shorter.

[image: this ares]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbar. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar for more information.